# Simple express-mongoose functions

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create a simple API using express and mongoose to query and process data from Mongo DB.

and from front end I'll use axios to call this and return the result and based on this result I'll route the app.

I created below simple function and it works as expected it fetches the object if it exists in the DB,
and return the object, but now I would like to assign this to a variable and compare the result? how to do it ?

> Login

```
async function login(username,password){
    try{
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
        const query=await UserModel.findOne({username:username, password:password});
        
        mongoose.connection.close();
        console.log(query);
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

> assuming this user exist in the db it will return the object like this:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId('65b9db9578f42ed5f3fa685e'),
  username: 'userxyz',
  password: '123456',
  __v: 0
}
```

but how to validate this if I assign to variable and compare with with passed user name and password it returns:Promise { <pending> }, what is best way to achieve this? because I couldn't assign this function to variable and check it results to perform input validation

Comment: Your `UserModel.findOne` has done the comparison and resolved with the result of the query which is stored in the variable `query`. You need to check if `query` is `null` which will mean no document matches and decide what to return from your `login` function. Login using axios/fetch is not as straightforward as with a regular form submission because you need to handle redirection on success/failure which is simple with a regular form submission.